# WordPress/PHP - How can I include a container div around every 9 images?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code:

```
<?php 
$images = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'pointb_portfolio_images', false);
$i = 0;
foreach ($images as $att) {
    $i++;
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($att, 'full');
    $src = $src[0];
    echo "<img src='$src' class='t$i'/>";
}
?>
```

What I would like to do, is for every 9 images, place a DIV container around them.  So it would be:

```
<div>9 images here</div>
<div>next 9 images here</div>
<div>next 9 images here</div>
```

I have an incremental class being applied to each image, and this would need to continue increasing upward.

I have been googling to try and find a solution for this, but I am struggling to find even the correct search query.

Would appreciate any assistance or tips so that I can accomplish what I need.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `%` (modulus) it finds the remainder. So what you do is you have an `if ($i % 9 == 0) ...` then close the 9 image div and open a new one.  That expression will validate as true once every 9 loops through.  You also have an opening `<div>` before the loop starts and a closing `</div>` after it's done.

```
<?php 
$images = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'pointb_portfolio_images', false);
$i = 0;

echo '<div>';

foreach ($images as $att) {
    // Moved this to the front of the loop so we don't have any empty div groups
    // in case 9 is a factor of the number
    if ($i > 0 && $i % 9 == 0) {
        echo '</div><div>';
    }

    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($att, 'full');
    $src = $src[0];

    // Added modulus to the class so now they will be t1, t2,... t8, t9, t1, t2...
    echo "<img src='$src' class='t" . ($i % 9 + 1) . "'/>";

    $i++;
}

echo '</div>';
?>
```

**Examples of what Modulus returns**

```
 0 % 9 = 0
 1 % 9 = 1
 2 % 9 = 2
 3 % 9 = 3
 4 % 9 = 4
 5 % 9 = 5
 6 % 9 = 6
 7 % 9 = 7
 8 % 9 = 8
 9 % 9 = 0
10 % 9 = 1
11 % 9 = 2
```

Comment: if ($i % 9 == 0) { $div = '<div>'; $divc = '</div>'; } else { $div = ''; $divc = ''; } 
echo $div."<img src='$src' class='t$i'/>".$divc;

Comment: @Ara I don't think that's what the OP wants. I think what they want is: `<div><img /><img /><img /><img /><img /><img /><img /><img /><img /></div><div><img /><img /><img /><img /><img /><img /><img /><img /><img /></div>

Comment: Just one question. If I also wanted a variation where the counter resets after 9 items, how would I do that also?

Comment: You can actually use modulus for that to. I'm assuming you want it for the class so you could do `echo "<img src='$src' class='" . ($i % 9) . "' />";

Comment: @ZachNicodemous I've updated my answer to show you how you can use modulus to make the classes for the images t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t1, t2, etc

Comment: Fantastic :) that is extremely helpful. I appreciate answers that not only give the answer but explains it too and yours has done just that :)